# What song was played during credits of the kingsman?

Tags: ending, soundtrack, credits, kingsman-the-secret-service

What song was played during the credits of *Kingsman: The Secret Service*? Unfortunately my mobile battery drained out hence I wasn't able to Shazam it.

Comment: Funny! how this question is down voted and closed and at the same time earned me a gold badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not seen it, but the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Secret_Service) for Kingsman says:
"A song from Take That's seventh studio album III, "Get Ready for It", will play during the end credits."

Is [this (YouTube link)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=4f59ZtVeTr0) the one?

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for! :) I looked up everywhere but Wikipedia!  How stupid of me :|